# game: kid & zombi moving different speeds, same loop fiddle, html5, javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developing this html5, javascript game.

**PROBLEM**

I need to animate the main character & the zombi with different fps (or animation timing) in order to give them the appearance of moving at different speeds.

So I want the zombi to move slower than the kid, but both working with a single loop (single setInterval)

How do I get that effect? https://jsfiddle.net/mc9jmc7j/

Optional: here animated with requestAnimationFrame() https://jsfiddle.net/mc9jmc7j/3/ I just cant control the speed

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); 
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 


//DRAWING/ANIMATING MAIN CHARACTER
////////////////////////////////////////////
var x =100;
var y =60;
var srcX;
var srcY;
var sheetWidth = 864;
var sheetHeight = 280;
var cols = 8;
var rows = 2;
var width = sheetWidth/cols;
var height = sheetHeight/rows;
var currentFrame =0;


function updateCharacterFrame(){
 currentFrame = ++ currentFrame% cols;
 srcX = currentFrame*width;
 srcY = 0;
 ctx.clearRect(x,y,width,height);
}

var character = new Image();
character.src="https://i1.wp.com/www.simplifiedcoding.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/character.png?w=864&ssl=1";

//--------------------------

function AnimateCharacter(){
updateCharacterFrame();
ctx.drawImage(character,srcX,srcY, width, height,x,y,60, 60)
}


//DRAWING/ANIMATING ZOMBI
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var ZombiX =10;
var ZombiY =60;
var ZombisrcX;
var ZombisrcY;
var ZombisheetWidth = 512;//512; 
var ZombisheetHeight = 516;//480; 
var Zombicols = 4;//4;
var Zombirows = 4;//4;
var Zombiwidth = ZombisheetWidth/Zombicols;
var Zombiheight = ZombisheetHeight/Zombirows;
var ZombicurrentFrame =0;

function updateZombiFrame(){
 ZombicurrentFrame = ++ ZombicurrentFrame% Zombicols; 

 ZombisrcX = ZombicurrentFrame*Zombiwidth;
 ZombisrcsrcY = 2*Zombiheight;
 ctx.clearRect(ZombiX,ZombiY,Zombiwidth,Zombiheight);
 


}
var zombi = new Image();
zombi.src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/6d86/f/2011/094/d/a/zombie_sprite_sheet_by_ceridwen64-d3d747n.png";

//--------------------------

function AnimateZombi(){
updateZombiFrame(); 
ctx.drawImage(zombi,ZombisrcX,ZombisrcsrcY, Zombiwidth, Zombiheight,ZombiX,ZombiY,60, 60)
}



function mainLoop(){
AnimateZombi();AnimateCharacter();
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

characterFPS = 20;
setInterval(function(){

 mainLoop();

},1000/characterFPS);
```

```css
#canvas{
  margin: 0 auto;
  border:1px solid #f0f0f0;
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Set a loop speed of 60fps (or whatever), and each frame move the character by a certain amount. The amount characters move changes depending on their speed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I took a stab at it by only updating the Zombi frame every x times (using `ZombieCalls` var) the character frame is called (it looks like the Zombi is moving slower this way than the character)

Doing it this way also keeps everything in the same interval like you wanted.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");


//DRAWING/ANIMATING MAIN CHARACTER
////////////////////////////////////////////
var x = 100;
var y = 60;
var srcX;
var srcY;
var sheetWidth = 864;
var sheetHeight = 280;
var cols = 8;
var rows = 2;
var width = sheetWidth / cols;
var height = sheetHeight / rows;
var currentFrame = 0;


function updateCharacterFrame() {
  currentFrame = ++currentFrame % cols;
  srcX = currentFrame * width;
  srcY = 0;
  ctx.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
}

var character = new Image();
character.src = "https://i1.wp.com/www.simplifiedcoding.net/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/character.png?w=864&ssl=1";

//--------------------------

function AnimateCharacter() {
  updateCharacterFrame();
  ctx.drawImage(character, srcX, srcY, width, height, x, y, 60, 60)
}


//DRAWING/ANIMATING ZOMBI
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var ZombiX = 10;
var ZombiY = 60;
var ZombisrcX;
var ZombisrcY;
var ZombisheetWidth = 512; //512; 
var ZombisheetHeight = 516; //480; 
var Zombicols = 4; //4;
var Zombirows = 4; //4;
var Zombiwidth = ZombisheetWidth / Zombicols;
var Zombiheight = ZombisheetHeight / Zombirows;
var ZombicurrentFrame = 0;
var ZombieCalls = 1;

function updateZombiFrame() {
  if (ZombieCalls % 4 === 0) {
    ZombicurrentFrame = ++ZombicurrentFrame % Zombicols;
  }
  ZombieCalls++;
  // reset ZombieCalls so it doesn't get too large
  if(ZombieCalls >= 400) ZombieCalls = 0;
  
  ZombisrcX = ZombicurrentFrame * Zombiwidth;
  ZombisrcsrcY = 2 * Zombiheight;
  ctx.clearRect(ZombiX, ZombiY, Zombiwidth, Zombiheight);



}
var zombi = new Image();
zombi.src = "https://orig00.deviantart.net/6d86/f/2011/094/d/a/zombie_sprite_sheet_by_ceridwen64-d3d747n.png";

//--------------------------

function AnimateZombi() {
  updateZombiFrame();
  ctx.drawImage(zombi, ZombisrcX, ZombisrcsrcY, Zombiwidth, Zombiheight, ZombiX, ZombiY, 60, 60)
}



function mainLoop() {
  AnimateZombi();
  AnimateCharacter();
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

characterFPS = 20;
setInterval(function() {

  mainLoop();

}, 1000 / characterFPS);
```

```css
#canvas {
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid #f0f0f0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you. question...so with this `if (ZombieCalls % 4 === 0) {` the zombi moves four times slower than the kid? .....If I add a third character, for example `turtle` & set it with `(TurtleCalls % 12=== 0) {` it would move 12 times slower than the kid ?

Comment: Hey Dan so the Zombi would move every 4th frame the character does so I think yes you can say it moves 4 times as slow and `TurtleCalls % 12` would move 12 times slower then the character. Also the ZombiCalls var should probably start at 1 since 0 % 4 = 0.  I changed that